# Need to merge a regex jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a code in jquery which check for password strength.
But I need to merge that match and get a alert if all the test passes.
I need it in seperate function. Check code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dmam4/).

```
<ul>
  <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
  <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></li>
  <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
  <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
</ul>

jQuery('#user-password').keyup(function() {
            var temp = jQuery('#user-password').val();

            if (temp.length < 8) {
                jQuery('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            } else {
                jQuery('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            }
            if (temp.match(/[A-z]/)) {
                jQuery('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                jQuery('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }
            if (temp.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
                jQuery('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                jQuery('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }
            if (temp.match(/\d/)) {
                jQuery('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                jQuery('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#user-password').on('keyup', function () {
        var temp = this.value,
            all  = $('#length, #letter, #capital, #number');

        $('#length').toggleClass('valid', temp.length > 8);
        $('#letter').toggleClass('valid', /\D/.test(temp));
        $('#capital').toggleClass('valid', /[A-Z]/.test(temp));
        $('#number').toggleClass('valid', /\d/.test(temp));

        if ( all.length === all.filter('.valid').length ) {
            alert('All valid !');
        }

    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dmam4/1/)